# How to use searchkick search method on an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I have a Project and a Meeting Model in my application.

Query in meetings controller is as follows:

```
all_meetings = Project.get_all_meetings @project
meetings = Kaminari.paginate_array(all_meetings).page(params[:page]).per params[:per_page]
render_collection meetings, Meeting
```

In project model:

```
def self.get_all_meetings project
    active_meetings =  project.meetings.without_deleted.order updated_at: :desc
    cancelled_meetings =  project.meetings.only_deleted.order updated_at: :desc
    active_meetings + cancelled_meetings
end
```

I want to use search method on all_meetings variable like all_meetings.search but getting error as

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `search' for #<Array:0x00007f20b0b74238>
Did you mean?  bsearch
               each):

app/controllers/api/v1/pm/meetings_controller.rb:9:in `index'
app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb:85:in `set_global'
app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb:117:in `handle_exceptions'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert this whole logic to elasticsearch functionalities. put pagination and "get_all_meetings" filtering mechanism to a searchkick where clause. you can add more data to elasticsearch indexes by overriding "serach_data" function.